# Retrieve Mac address in powershell and convert it to decimal format

Tags: powershell

I can easily get Mac address in powershell by:

```
$localMac=Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | select macaddress
echo $localMac[0]
```

The result is:

```
macaddress                                                                                                                                                   
----------                                                                                                                                                   
E8:21:32:E5:F4:6A
```

How can I change result to decimal format in powershell? Just for example 7436378647

I tried

```
$MacAddressConverted = $localMac[0] -replace '(:|-|\.)'
echo $MacAddressConverted
```

It returns

```
@{macaddress=E82132E5F46A}
```

It's close what I would like to achive but it still has @{macadress= and it's not converted to decimal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$MAC = ((Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
        Where-Object MACAddress |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty MACAddress -First 1
    ) -replace ':'
)
[int64]$('0x' + $MAC)
```

**EDIT:** to get a more verbose version with a `[PSCustomObject]`

```
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | 
    Where-Object MacAddress | ForEach {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        'MAC_hex' = $_.MacAddress
        'MAC_dec' = [int64]("0x$($_.MacAddress.Replace(':',''))")
        'ServiceName' = $_.ServiceName
        'Description'=$_.Description}
}
```

Sample output:

```
MAC_hex                  MAC_dec ServiceName Description
-------                  ------- ----------- -----------
0A:00:27:xx:xx:xx 10995770599999 VBoxNetAdp  VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3
00:23:54:xx:xx:xx   151749299999 rt640x64    Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
    Where-Object { $_.MacAddress } |
    ForEach-Object { [convert]::ToInt64($_.MacAddress.Replace(':', ''), 16) }
```

It gives the next result on my laptop:

```
147163166963
19938372466931
```